# Camera preview is chubby

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to implement camera features on my application. Since it's my first time doing so, I'm running a little issue with my camera preview.

**My current layout looks like this:**

[image]

**Which is producing a preview like this:**

[image]

**However I want something like this:**

[image]

**And here is the code for my camera:**

```
public class FragmentPhoto extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private Camera camera;     

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);

        final TextureView textureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored, the Camera does all the work for us
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Update your view here!
    }
}
```

Is there any way to crop the camera? To not make the preview this chubby? What is the best aproach to do this?

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout as root, put your SurfaceView (or SurfaceTexture as i see you are using that) as your first child element and set your dimensions to fill the screen. Place your other child elements in the RelativeLayout accordingly.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but if I do this way, when I capture the image I will get the full screen picture right? and not only that specific square size (the textureview size) right?

Comment: Nope, unless you are taking a screenshot with your phone. Taking a picture by using one of your Camera callbacks will return exactly what the Camera "sees".